# Trying to set a range

Tags: excel, vba

```
  Set rng = ActiveSheet.(D4:K57)
```

the following code throws "Expected: identifier or bracketed expression". What is the error here?

Comment: You haven't set the range properly, `ActiveSheet.range(D4:K57)`

Comment: Thanks! Although it worked when quotation marks were around D4:K57.

Comment: [Check this out to improve coding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/)

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveSheet.range("D4:K57")
```

Normally I would dim the range though,

```
Dim rng as range
set rng=range("D4:K57")

rng.select' or whatever you want to do with it
```

Comment: What's the value in adding the dim